# Beautiful Soup Exact tag data

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract some data from HTML page. What I am doing is:

```
list=soup.find_all('td', {'align': 'left', 'valign': None})
print list[0]
```

It gives me

```
<td align="left">\n<h3>Name XYZ</h3>\n CTS SANSKRUTI LAYOUT, 90 FEET RAOD, THAKUR  COMPLEX, <br/>KANDIVALI EAST,<br/>Mumbai  MAHARASHTRA-400101</td>
```

But I want output like:

```
Name: Name XYZ, Add: CTS SANSKRUTI LAYOUT, 90 FEET RAOD, THAKUR  COMPLEX, KANDIVALI EAST, Mumbai  MAHARASHTRA-400101
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

find_all will return a list of tag, so when you access the first item in the list `list[0]`, it will return the first tag, like you output

if you want to extract text for tag, you can use tag.text, in your case

```
list[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that there are two methods for that, depending on what you are looking for.

Im not sure whether the "name" and "add" strings in front of your desired output are typos or not, so here are the two possible ways I see on how to do it:

1. In the case you simply want to extract all the text beneath each tag of your `list_tags` obtained from the `find_all` method, without any manipulations such as separating each word, go for the `get_text()` method.

With it, you could opt for a simple list comprehension like:

```
>>> simple_uni_text = [tag.get_text() for tag in list_tags]
>>> simple_uni_text
[u'\nName XYZ\n CTS SANSKRUTI LAYOUT, 90 FEET RAOD, THAKUR  COMPLEX, KANDIVALI EAST,Mumbai  MAHARASHTRA-400101', u'\nName ABC\n DUT WITHOUT LAYIN, 45 FOOT AODR, RUKTHA  SIMPLE, BOMBAY WEST,BOMBAY RASHTRAMAHA-400101']
>>> len(simple_uni_text)
>>> 2 # I pretended the list_tags to have two tags, so it generated a list of length two!
```

2. The `stripped_strings` *generator*.

Its maybe a trickier method. But you could gain in precision.

```
>>> uni_stripped_words = []
>>> for tag in list_tags:
        for string in tag.stripped_strings:
            uni_stripped_words.append(string)
>>> uni_stripped_words
[u'Name XYZ', u'CTS SANSKRUTI LAYOUT, 90 FEET RAOD, THAKUR  COMPLEX,', u'KANDIVALI EAST,', u'Mumbai  MAHARASHTRA-400101', u'Name ABC', u'DUT WITHOUT LAYIN, 45 FOOT AODR, RUKTHA  SIMPLE,', u'BOMBAY WEST,', u'BOMBAY RASHTRAMAHA-400101']
>>> len(uni_stripped_words)
8
```

Here you separate each string that are found beneath each teag of your list_tags from another. Thus, if you indeed want to add the following "Name" and "Add" in front of your text, then it could better correspond to your needs.

```
>>> for word in uni_stripped_words:
        print word


    Name XYZ
    CTS SANSKRUTI LAYOUT, 90 FEET RAOD, THAKUR  COMPLEX,
    KANDIVALI EAST,
    Mumbai  MAHARASHTRA-400101
    Name ABC
    DUT WITHOUT LAYIN, 45 FOOT AODR, RUKTHA  SIMPLE,
    BOMBAY WEST,
    BOMBAY RASHTRAMAHA-400101 # Sorry for the weird text example haha
```

I however find the second method less controllable. There are, for instance, sometimes unexpected characters. Personnally I prefer to concatenate when writing out the output to a file!

Anyway, in both cases, don't forget that the resulting lists will contain extracted text of unicode type.

Cheers